# CUDA install stopped my second monitor working?

Tags: xrandr, hdmi, cuda

I'm using a Lenovo [ThinkPad P50](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-p/ThinkPad-P50/p/22TP2WPWP50). When I boot into my Windows partition it does work, but I have no luck with Ubuntu 18.04.

I was attempting to install CUDA earlier, and when I restarted my laptop, the second monitor was no longer working.

I tried purging and reinstalling the NVIDIA drivers but I have had no success.

When I run "xrandr" in command line, the HDMI port is no longer present, the output is as follows:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.05*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32
```

How do I restore my second monitor in Ubuntu 18.04 ?

Comment: I was issued one of these machines for five years. it. was. total. pain. I recommend seeking out a different computer, there are _lots_ if p50-specific hacks here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_ThinkPad_P50

Comment: I had success by never using a laptop dock, and also using a display port mst hub for mini dp from the right side of the laptop. something like this: https://sgcdn.startech.com/005329/media/sets/MSTMDP123DP_Manual/MSTMDP123DP.pdf as best I know, this isn't a driver software issue, its a laptop firmware issue, I would not count-on and wait-for lenovo to fix it.

Comment: @ThorSummoner, unfortunately I am issued this through my PhD budget so a new one is unlikely. I am going to do a total reboot of the OS tomorrow and see if that works, but if not, I will likely have a good excuse for a new laptop I guess!